# How to run two command simultaneously in Powershell?

Tags: loops, powershell, mouse, block

I need to code a loop in Powershell that forces mouse position until another script is running.

```
#Mouse blocking starts now
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$screen = [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::VirtualScreen
$screen.Width = 1
$screen.Height = 1
do

{
    [Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = "$($screen.width),$($screen.height)"
}while (.\file.ps1)
```

This does not work.
Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [PSJob](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847783.aspx) to launch the first script and the check whether the job has completed inside the `while` condition:

```
$MyFilePath = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot file.ps1
$MyJob = Start-Job { & $args[0] } -ArgumentList $MyFilePath 

do
{
    [Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = "$($screen.width),$($screen.height)"
    # Maybe wait a little 
    Start-Sleep -MilliSeconds 200
} while ($MyJob.State -eq "Running")
```

Comment: @ppiotrek have you tried specifying the full path to the script? ie. `C:\path\to\file.ps1`

Comment: Yes, I have but it opens the job as a txt file in Notepad. This is regardless using the full path. How can we force it to run is as an app in PS?

Comment: Try with the call operator (`&`): `{& C:\path\to\file.ps1}`

Comment: It worked, thank you a lot! Now I have another problem - if I'm using the full path, I can't use the script on a different machines in different places/folders. How can I get around it? Is there any way?

Comment: @ppiotrek Updated answer to show how you can construct the file path outside the Job scriptblock and then pass it as an argument

Comment: Thanks mate, you've saved my bacon!

Comment: If his answer provided a solution to your question please mark it as the accepted solution by clicking the checkmark just below the upvote/downvote buttons on the left.